# Paywall policy for non game page tabs

Tags: tabs, policy, facebook-credits

I spent a while looking through Facebook's polices but couldn't find anything mentioning this so hopefully someone here may know.

I want to create a page tab and put a lot of the content behind a paywall, do I need to accept Facebook Credits in addition to the other payment options?

If send the user away from Facebook to signup do I still need to accept Credits?

This is not a Game so the game specific policies don't apply
I am sorry if this is the wrong place to ask a question such as this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your application is not a game, then the credits migration requirement does not apply to your app whether it's an app in a tab or on canvas (ie apps.facebook.com/YOUR_APP). Only game developers who are accepting payments on their canvas app(s) are *required* to use Facebook Credits as their sole payment system. There is also an [FAQ](https://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=210316649012192) on Facebook's help center which explains this.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't seen the FAQ post.

Comment: I would imagine this change would come at some point and non game apps will be required to accept credits.